# DBT RecursionError

Tags: dbt

I've installed `dbt` on my Windows PC.
After creating the necessary configuration, I've executed `dbt debug` successfully.
I tried executing `dbt run`. I have a local Postgres installed, and I'm getting the following error:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

###### Output of `dbt --version`

```
installed version: 1.0.4
   latest version: 1.0.4

Up to date!

Plugins:
  - postgres: 1.0.4 - Up to date!
```

Anything I can do?

Comment: I don't have an answer but after upgrading to Python 3.10 and re-installing, I'm also getting this error

Comment: Also seeing a recursion depth error in Python 3.10.3 when running `dbt clean` with a minimal dbt_project.yml  with just name, version, config-version properties defined. This is _not_ happening with Python version 3.9.11.

Comment: Did some more digging. Has to do with logbook using deprecated threading functions. The use of the deprecated functions causes log warnings to be emitted during logging, and that causes the infinite loop. Replacing `currentThread` with `current_thread` and `getName()` with `name` in logbook.concurrency fixes the problem.

Comment: Ah, looks like someone at dbt-labs is aware of the issue: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4560

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue using dbt with Python 3.10: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4560

dbt supports Python versions up to 3.9: https://docs.getdbt.com/faqs/install-python-compatibility

The solution is to use Python 3.9 instead of 3.10.